# ethers, cannot map abi from json

Tags: typescript, abi, ethers.js, uniswap

I'm trying to import a contract using ethers.  I'm getting an error:

> ..\node_modules@ethersproject\abi\src.ts\interface.ts:100
> defineReadOnly(this, "fragments", abi.map((fragment) => {

My source file looks like so:

```
import { ethers } from 'ethers';
import IUniswapV3PoolABI from '@uniswap/v3-core/artifacts/contracts/interfaces/IUniswapV3Pool.sol/IUniswapV3Pool.json' 
import env from 'dotenv'
env.config();

const poolAddress = '0x7109C674e52b14FCFb8A04ffe254f454f9C61C18'
const INFURA_URL_MAINNET = process.env.INFURA_URL_MAINNET
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(INFURA_URL_MAINNET);

const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(
    poolAddress,
    IUniswapV3PoolABI as any,
    provider
)
```

These are my dependencies in the package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@uniswap/sdk-core": "^3.0.1",
  "@uniswap/v3-sdk": "^3.8.2",
  "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
  "ethers": "^5.1.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@ethersproject/experimental": "^5.4.0",
  "@typechain/ethers-v5": "^7.0.0",
  "@types/node": "^18.11.9",
  "typechain": "^5.0.0",
  "typescript": "^4.8.4"
}
```

**Note:** I also tried this with the newer version of the packages when I originally got the error, I figured it might be due to uniswap using an old version of the ABI files so I cloned the dependency version from the `uniswap/interface`

How can I create an ethers contract?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the Json is more than the abi, so I need to call the abi property on the json

```
const { abi: V3PoolABI } = IUniswapV3PoolABI

const poolContract = new ethers.Contract(
    poolAddress,
    V3PoolABI as any,
    provider
)
```